# mysql Array in datatable shows 1 character

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ruby, datatable

I'm trying to fill a datatable via AJAX and Mysql with Ruby - Sinatra and Haml files. 
I've finally found how to create my datatable working fine with static data but now I'm trying to change this to data from my mysql database working with AJAX statement.

The problem is my datatable returns only 1 character in each row and shows it only in 1 column like this:

[image]

I think the problem might be my array I return, who looks like this:

[image]

here is some code in my ruby file who returns the data:

```
get '/allesites' do
  res = Array.new
  @alleSites = con2.query("SELECT * FROM dbportal.tblSites", :as => :array)
  @alleSites.each do |row|
  res.push(row)
  end
  return res.to_json
end
```

last but not least here is the jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/allesites",
  type: "get",
  success: function(data){
    $("#test").dataTable({
      "data": data,
      "columns": [
       { "title": "nummer"},
       { "title": "naam"},

      ]

    });

  },
```

Finally I'm also having an error like this: 
[image]

Comment: Don't use screen shots and images to show us text. Instead, copy, paste and format the text. That allows us to reuse text if necessary without typing it in, plus it lets the search engines find the text, which they then use to help others find your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just Changed something in my ajax-request and It seems to be fixed right now !

```
 "data": jQuery.parseJSON(data),
```

I just tried something and it worked, great !!